# Change specific row and column in Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I want to change specific row and column in Datagridview.
when I enter specific data in column `x` it will return any specific value in column `Y`. Otherwise data in column `x`  will return value 7777 in column `Y`

[image]

But when I run this code, there were nothing change in column `Y` :

```
Private Sub Table1DataGridView_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles Table1DataGridView.CellEndEdit

    'For e.ColumnIndex + 1
    If e.ColumnIndex = 2 Then
        If Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value) = 5 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 5

        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value) = 7 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 7

        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value) = 1 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 6
            '1
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(1).Cells(2).Value) = 1.5 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(1).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 7.326
            '2
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(2).Cells(2).Value) = 2 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(2).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 6.374
            '3
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(3).Cells(2).Value) = 2.5 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(3).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 4.702
            '4
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(4).Cells(2).Value) = 2 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(4).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 1.321
            '5
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(5).Cells(2).Value) = 2.5 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(5).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 0.035
            '6
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(6).Cells(2).Value) = 4 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(6).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 0.205
            '7
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(7).Cells(2).Value) = 2.5 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(7).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 4.969
            '8
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(16).Cells(2).Value) = 4 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(16).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 1.588
            '9
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(17).Cells(2).Value) = 2.5 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(17).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 4.696
            '10
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(18).Cells(2).Value) = 2.5 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(18).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 0.866
            '11
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(19).Cells(2).Value) = 2 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(19).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 1.881
            '12
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(20).Cells(2).Value) = 2.5 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(20).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 4.702
            '13
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(21).Cells(2).Value) = 2 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(21).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 6.515
            '14
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(22).Cells(2).Value) = 1.5 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(22).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 6.92671744
        Else
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 7777

        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Then, I try to change this code, but return some same value at column `Y` :

```
Private Sub Table1DataGridView_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles Table1DataGridView.CellEndEdit

    'For e.ColumnIndex + 1
    If e.ColumnIndex = 2 Then
        If Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value) = 5 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 5

        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value) = 7 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 7

        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value) = 1 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 6
            '1
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(1).Cells(2).Value) = 1.5 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 7.326
            '2
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(2).Cells(2).Value) = 2 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 6.374
            '3
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(3).Cells(2).Value) = 2.5 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 4.702
            '4
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(4).Cells(2).Value) = 2 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 1.321
            '5
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(5).Cells(2).Value) = 2.5 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 0.035
            '6
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(6).Cells(2).Value) = 4 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 0.205
            '7
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(7).Cells(2).Value) = 2.5 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 4.969
            '8
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(16).Cells(2).Value) = 4 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 1.588
            '9
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(17).Cells(2).Value) = 2.5 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 4.696
            '10
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(18).Cells(2).Value) = 2.5 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 0.866
            '11
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(19).Cells(2).Value) = 2 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 1.881
            '12
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(20).Cells(2).Value) = 2.5 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 4.702
            '13
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(21).Cells(2).Value) = 2 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 6.515
            '14
        ElseIf Val(Table1DataGridView.Rows(22).Cells(2).Value) = 1.5 Then
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 6.92671744
        Else
            Table1DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Value = 7777

        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the DataGridView is databound, you need modify the databound object not the grid directly. You can access that object through the DataBoundItem property:

```
Dim obj As MyObject = Table1DataGridView.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem
obj.MyProperty = newValue
```

just set MyObject and MyProperty as appropriate

Comment: I got an error at `MyObject`. `MyObject` is not declared.
Can I do like this at row 1:
`Dim obj As MyObject = Table1DataGridView.1.DataBoundItem
        obj.MyProperty = 7.326`

Sorry for my basic level. can you show the example.

Comment: You need to change MyObject and MyPropertty to whatever your grid is bound to. How are you populating your grid?

Comment: I'm populating the grid by using Windows.form.datagridview. I dragged Table1 from the data-source.

Comment: Whatever you control is bound to, you need to go and change the source of the data not the control itself.

Comment: MyObject and MyProperty is referring to my row and column ?

Comment: It sounds like you are binding to a DataTable do you need to change that. Dim dt As New DataTable
dt = (DirectCast(Table1DataGridView.DataSource, DataTable))